# Laravel admin フォームのselect要素をDBから参照するには

Tags: php, laravel

Laraveladminでフォームを作成しています。
セレクト要素を構築する場合は

```
$directors = [
'John'  => 1,
'Smith' => 2,
'Kate'  => 3,
];

$form->select('director', 'Director')->options($directors);
```

としてselectの値を配列で渡す形になるのですが
この値がDBに保持されている場合はどのような形で参照するのがベストなのでしょうか？

私の中では

```
$directors = DB::table('directors')->get();
```

という形で参照した値を変換して渡す方法しか思い浮かばないのですが・・
このままだとエラーになるので、
'val' => 'Option name'の形に変換する必要があります・・。

初歩的なことかもしれませんがよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
こちらの書き方で参照することができました！

```
$form->select('director', 'Director')->options(
    DB::table('oga_section')->pluck('director_name','director_id')
);
```